# Tags component not found in Joomla admin

Tags: joomla, tags, admin

I'm trying to access the Tags component manager (administrator/index.php?option=com_tags), but gives a 404 error (**View not found [name, type, prefix]: tags, html, tagsView**)

Tags is working ok, I can add a new on a article, but I can't manage.

Using Joomla 3.6.5 and tested using mod_rewrite on/off.

Is there any one experiencing this?

Comment: I tested it on Joomla 3.6.5. It works correctly.

Comment: Can you go to extension manager and confirm it is published?

Answer (score 0):

The tags extension is a protected extension, so technically it can't be disabled. Nevertheless, I suggest that you check if the extension is disabled by searching for "Tags" under "Extensions" -> "Manage".

My guess is that the folder `administrator/components/com_tags` folder is missing (or doesn't have the necessary read permissions) or you have some corruption in your assets table. Use the ACL Manager to fix the latter, and copy the com_tags folder from a fresh Joomla install (and fix the permissions) in the case of the former.